# Use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow5}\sqrt{x-1}=2$ by taking $\epsilon=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was trying to solve this exercise. I did some steps but can't find $\delta$. The steps are as follows:

Since $\varepsilon=1>0$, we will find $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\sqrt{x-1}-2\right|<\epsilon$
whenever $\left|x-5\right|<\delta$

Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left   |\sqrt{x-1}-2\right|<1\\
-1 & <\sqrt{x-1}-2 & <1\\
1 & <\sqrt{x-1}< & 3\\
1 & <x-1< & 9\\
2 & <x< & 10\\
-3 & <x-5< & 5
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, how I will find appropriate $\delta$?

Comment: If you want to show a limit, you can't pick any particular value for $\epsilon$; the condition has to be true necessarily for *all* $\epsilon > 0$, meaning it must be chosen arbitrarily (rather than = any particular value)

Answer (score 1):

$|x-5|<\delta \iff -\delta < x-5 < \delta$

You need to find a $\delta$ such the $-3 < x-5 < 5$ holds whenever $-\delta < x-5 < \delta$ holds.

You can check that the above is true whenever $\delta \le 3$.